# Setting default collation for all table in MySQL store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, global-variables, collation

My stored procedure has more than 5 create tables statement. Is there a way to     pick the default collation that was set in global variable by these create     tables statement without going through individual create table statement.

```
-- SAMPLE BLOCK A --   
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;   

SET @createTable = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE "abc"(   
record_id VARCHAR(255),   
member VARCHAR(255),   
name VARCHAR(255)   
)CHARACTER SET 'utf8'    
COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");   

PREPARE create_table_statement FROM @createTable;   
EXECUTE create_table_statement;   
DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_table_statement;   

-- SAMPLE BLOCK B--   
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS def;   

SET @createTable1 = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE "def"(   
address VARCHAR(255),   
member_gender VARCHAR(255),   
member_age VARCHAR(255)     
)CHARACTER SET 'utf8'    
COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");   

PREPARE create_table_statement1 FROM @createTable1;   
EXECUTE create_table_statement1;   
DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_table_statement1;   
.   
.
```

Comment: you have multiple solutions. You can edit your configuration file or after you logged in into mysql and set default collations for your user

Comment: I am working in corporate company. I don't have DBA access to edit in configuration. I need to change in procedure level not in configuration level.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You can use above statement while creating your table.

Answer (score 0):

There is two options:

1: Use a local variable that you can change to affect all creation tables

```
-- SAMPLE BLOCK A --   
set @character_set = 'utf8';
set @default_collation = 'utf8_unicode_ci';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;   

-- use that variables to build the SQL:

SET @createTable = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE "abc"(   
record_id VARCHAR(255),   
member VARCHAR(255),   
name VARCHAR(255)   
)CHARACTER SET '",@character_set,"'    
COLLATE '",@default_collation,"'");   

 -- same for next
```

2: Set database default character set and collation, when you set that default values: all new tables created without specific character set or collation will use that as default.

```
 CREATE DATABASE `your_database`
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```